# substitute 'which apt' to $(which apt)

Tags: substitute

i want to substitute the text `'which apt'` to `$(which apt)`.

```
:s/'\&.*'/$(\0)
```

does substitute to `$('which apt')`. How can i leave those single quotes out on the substitution, so that just $(..) appears?

---

**EDIT**

```
:s/'\zs\&.*\ze'/$(\0)
```

results in `$('which apt)'`. Although the regex should match any character between the two ', as i marked them as outside of the selection. i don't know if i did sth wrong?

Comment: Use `\zs` and `\ze`.  See `:help \zs`.

Comment: I'm certain that `\&` doesn't do what you think it does...although I don't know exactly *what* you think it does.  :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
:s/'\(.\{-}\)'/$(\1)/g
```

Search part:

```
'            single quote
 \(.\{-}\)   any character — . —, as few as possible — \{-} —,
             captured for reuse in the replacement — \(...\) —
          '  single quote
```

Replacement part:

```
$(           replace the first quote
  \1         reuse the capture group
    )        replace the second quote
```

Comment: Huh, I thought when using `{curly braces}` you have to backslash escape both of them, e.g. `/\(cat\)\{3\}/` to match `catcatcat`.  Is `\{-}` a typo?

Comment: Also: Thanks, I didn't know about the "minimal match" quantifier; I usually would just use `:s/'\([^']*\)'/$(\1)/g`

Comment: No, only the first `{` needs to be escaped.